# On arrows in Tikz cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, arrows

So I am getting used to using tikz-cd package to draw relatively straightforward commutative diagrams. I have two questions.

**Question 1**  Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt, draft]{amsart}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, matrix}
% With tons of other packages not relevant here I guess
\begin{document}
 % With some text ....
\[ 
\begin{tikzcd}
Y \arrow[dashrightarrow]{d} \arrow{rd} &  \\
Y_{0} \arrow{r}{\pi_{0}} & X \\
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

What happens here is that the arrow tips for the diagonal arrow is extremely light compared to the other two, you can see that in the picture below. I would like to know how to fix that. 
[image]

**Question 2** In the following diagram, (which also suffers from the same issues of question 1 above), I would want to fix the hook on the arrow labelled i so that it points the correct way (and perhaps make it more prominent).

[image]

Here is the code I am using for that part.

```
  \[
  \begin{tikzcd}[column sep =small] 
   & (X_{0},x)\arrow[hookrightarrow]{dl}{i}\arrow[hookrightarrow]{dr}{i^{\prime}}
     &   \\  
   (X,x) \arrow{dr} \arrow{rr}
   & & (X^{\prime}, x) \arrow{dl} \\
   & (U,u)
     & 
  \end{tikzcd}
  \]
```

Comment: Re 1: This is most likely a viewer issue. I don’t have the same problem. Try zooming and or using another [tag:viewer]. Code snippet 2 is not compilable as it is (`{i^{\prime}` is missing a `}` and can simply be written as `{i'}`) and empty lines are not allowed in math-mode. What is the “correct” way. More prominent? It suffers the same rendering issues in your view as the diagonal arrow.

Comment: The arrow thickness issue might be caused by an old installation of TikZ?

Comment: I don't see thickness problems. For the hook, say `\arrow[left hook->]{dl}`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel the issue with     { i^{\prime}   has been fixed thanks for pointing that out. I was using the document viewer on ubuntu and after changing the document viewer to orca my question one seems to be no question at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The thickness problem seems to be a viewer issue. For the hook in the second diagram you can use a direct TikZ expression for the arrow; with the key `swap` you can change the side of the arrow chosen for the label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small] 
&  
  (X_{0},x) 
  \arrow[hookrightarrow]{dr}{i'}
  \arrow[left hook->,swap]{dl}{i} % <-- reflect the direction of the hook
\\
(X,x)
  \arrow{dr} \arrow{rr} 
&&
(X', x)
  \arrow{dl} \\
&
(U,u)  
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

It's easier to type `i'` for `i^{\prime}` and the output is exactly the same. Never leave blank lines in the code for a `tikzcd`.

[image]